# how to fix radio button and display the results

Tags: android

hi im having trouble fixing my radio button i am new to coding and im making a simple calculator however i do not know how to fix this problem.

public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
            float height=0;
            float age = 0;
            float weight=0;
            float result=0;

            height= Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
            age= Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
            weight= Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
```

my issue relates to the if statement the equation is not correct because it say that is doesn't recognise the  "*" how to i format the equation to make it work without deleting the equation also if their are other mistakes in this code i would appresiate if you can fix that as well thank you

```
            if (male.isChecked())  {

                result = (66.47 + (13.75 * w) + (5.0 * h) - (6.75 * a));

            }

            else if (female.isChecked()){

                result = (665.09 + (9.56 * w) + (1.84 * h) - (4.67*a));

            }


            r.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
result = (66.47 + (13.75 * w) + (5.0 * h) - (6.75 * a));
```

to

```
result = (66.47 + (13.75 * weight) + (5.0 * height) - (6.75 * age));
```

You can not apply multiplication on `w`, `h` or `a` as they are `View`s.

You need to get their values and then perform multiplication,

Comment: thank for the help but i came across a different problem relating to this i have used a radiogroup instead of a normal radio button how would i fix the code as a error show up on the if statement for the "isChecked"